# list assignment index out of range while resizing my image size

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
x_train_all_new = []
np.array(x_train_all_new)

for i in range(len(x_train_all)):
  x_train_all_new[i] = tf.image.resize(x_train_all[i], (HEIGHT, WIDTH)) /255.0
```

x_train_all is a list of size 50000

Showing the error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-d3ea4cc1ee84> in <module>
      1 for i in range(len(x_train_all)):
----> 2   x_train_all_new[i] = tf.image.resize(x_train_all[i], (HEIGHT, WIDTH)) /255.0

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: What is the type and size of `x_train_all_new`? How did that object get created?

Comment: What is 'i' you are using 'element' and assigining 'i' inside to loop

Comment: Maybe the value of `i` stuck around from a previous loop. `element` is unused.

Comment: I have edited the question for more information. Also the shape of x_train_all is (50000, 32, 32, 3)

Comment: You have not clarified what `i` is, as it is not iterated over and may have retained its value from a previous loop.

Comment: what do you mean by that I haven't clarified what i is? I am iterating over a for loop so i is a control variable here. Sorry, I'm not able to get you.

Comment: `x_train_all_new` is an empty list - the statement `np.array(x_train_all_new)` has absolutely no effect, you are throwing away the result.  An empty list has no valid indexes, you cannot store anything in it via indexing.  You'd need to use `.append()` (or possibly `.extend()`) to add any contents to it.